# Check if STDIN or STDOUT is a TTY in Lua

Tags: lua, pipe, stdout, stdin, tty

In C you have `isatty(file_descriptor)` and you can pass 0 as the file descriptor for STDIN and 1 for STDOUT.

How can I assert that in Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything built-in but you could always shell out for a test with `[` or `tty` (obviously somewhat non-portable) if you didn't want to use a C module that exposed `isatty`.

C modules that expose `isatty`:

1. [`lua-isatty`](https://bitbucket.org/telemachus/lua-isatty)
2. [`lua-term`](https://github.com/hoelzro/lua-term)
3. [`luaposix`](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/)

there are probably others too.

Comment: @siffiejoe Indeed. I'd meant to check and confirm that it supported it and add it and then got distracted.